# Given $n$ points that can be freely arranged on a plane, how many lines at max can be formed with exactly $m$ out of $n$ points on each?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

When $n$=10 and $m$=4, I know the answer is 5 (pentagram). However, when $n$=11 and $m$=3, after some thought, I found the solution with 9 lines, as shown below, but no idea if this's the "at max" solution.

Does the general formula for this problem exist in a relatively simple form?

[image]

Comment: If the general formula is hard to answer, pls lmk, the question can then be modified to: After given a specific m and n, how to approach this problem (instead of drawing randomly like me...) and how do we know if the solution we figure out is the "at max" one?

Comment: This appears to be an open problem. Search _orchard-planting problem_. There are some useful links here: http://oeis.org/A003035

Comment: @nickgard _orchard-planting problem_ is exactly what I was looking for, much appreciated!